# Combining bubbled events into a single event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**EDIT:** I finally figured it out. It's quite a lot of code, so check out [the zip!!](http://xmoo.dk/dl/checkboxlist.zip)

I have a control, with multiple controls, which contain multiple checkboxes.  
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu7zD.gif)

When pressing "Submit" I'd like, if any checkboxes have changed, to fire an event containing two Lists - one containing the checkboxes which check-mark were removed and one containing the checkboxes that's been checked.

Hooking up on the CheckedChanged-event is no problem and currently I just add the checkboxes to the added/removed lists in their container, but when can I fire the event in the container with the populated lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to combine the events.

This also gives you the functionality to see exactly what have been selected and what have been removed since last postback in a CheckBoxList (well, it's not really a CheckBoxList, but it works pretty much the same way).

[Download the code here](http://xmoo.dk/dl/checkboxlist.zip)